# Best application for stained concrete patio - shedding overhanging trees?

Tags: concrete, staining

Old concrete patio -- shedding maple trees stain the concrete. Powerwashing not remedying.  What application would render the best appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Acid etching. You have a few options here. Phosphoric Acid or Muriatic Acid

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning the patio, apply a stain so that present and further staining from leaves doesn't show.